# How to set Perforce P4LOG size in Mac

Tags: perforce, p4v, perforce-client-spec

I am unable to connect to my P4 repository through P4V or Intellij Idea, the error shown is as below in my Mac:

> The filesystem 'P4LOG' has only 0B free, but the server configuration
>   requires at least 10M available

Looks like the repository connection is refused when any P4 client is unable to log in its corresponding log file due to size limits. Can you please help me in finding which file to tweak for this setting and how (the syntax part)?

I have p4 command line and GUI utilities installed but cannot find any filesystem location with the following command at "/" location:

```
sudo find . -name '*P4LOG*'
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that the hard disk on your server has filled up.

You can't fix this by reconfiguring the server (at least, not easily).

Instead, you need to sign on to the server machine and make more disk space available.

Perhaps, there are old backups or old log files that have accumulated, that you can delete, after (preferably) copying them to an external backup device for long-term storage.

It may take a little while to determine why the hard disk on your server filled up. Maybe, somebody has been submitting more files than you expected, or submitting larger files than you expected. Sometimes, someone submits a single very large file, by accident, that they didn't intend to submit, and that uses up all the disk space on the server.

Once you have either added more disk space to the server, or found and removed unnecessary items which are using up space, the server will resume normal operations.

Comment: Hi Bryan, thanks for your reply... After 24 hours, the problem got fixed automatically, may be it was a server side issue...